# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

As i wrote this code `$this->setlist();` am this error, before writing this line I was not experiencing any errors, can you help me with this one?

```
public function setlist(){
    $mysql = new Mysql();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM student where cohortid = '$this->cohort' && programid = '$this->program && departmentid = '$this->department'";
    $mysql->execute($query);
    while($row = $mysql->fetch_array()){
        $this->list[] = $row;
    }
    array_unshift($this->list, "test");
    unset($this->list[0]);
}


public function display_id_firstname_and_lastname(){
    *$this->setlist();*
    $html = new Html();
    $html->table("table table-bordered");

    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "S#"; $html->closecolumn();  $html->column(); echo "FirstName"; $html->closecolumn(); $html->column(); echo "LastName"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();

    foreach($this->list as $key => $value){
        $html->row();
        $html->column(); echo $key; $html->closecolumn(); $html->column(); echo $value['firstname']; $html->closecolumn();
        $html->column(); echo $value['lastname']; $html->closecolumn();
        $html->closerow();

    }

    $html->closetable();
}
```

Comment: Could you `echo` the SQL before you execute it.

Comment: `'$this->program` <<< right there.

Comment: thanks mate, it solved it @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 3):

First you are missing a `'` around one of your variables.

Second you should use `AND` and not `&&`

Third if you want to get values from an objects property wrap the field in `{}` when used inside a double quoted string literal.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM student 
    WHERE cohortid = '{$this->cohort}' 
      AND programid = '{$this->program}' 
      AND departmentid = '{$this->department}'";
```

Comment: thanks mate, it solved the error @RiggsFolly

Comment: It is normal to accept an answer that solved your issue. It lets other know you have an answer so they dont continue answering and also tells others that might have similiar issues how it was solved

Comment: yes, i'll help them. @RiggsFolly